# GIF LZW decompression hints?

Tags: c, gif, lzw

I've read through numerous articles on GIF LZW decompression, but I'm still confused as to how it works or how to solve, in terms of coding, the more fiddly bits of coding.

As I understand it, when I get to the  byte stream in the GIF for the LZW compressed data, the stream tells me:

Minimum code size, AKA number of bits the first byte starts off with.

Now, as I understand it, I have to either add one to this for the clear code, or add two for clear code and EOI code. But I'm confused as to which of these it is?

So say I have 3 colour codes (01, 10, 11), with EOI code assumed (as 00) will the byte that follows the minimum code size (of 2) be 2 bits, or will it be 3 bits factoring in the clear code? Or is the clear code/EOI code both already factored into the minimum size?

The second question is, what is the easiest way to read in dynamically sized bits from a file? Because reading an odd numbers of bits (3 bits, 12 bits etc) from an even numbered byte (8) sounds like it could be messy and buggy?

Comment: Could someone give any hints on this?

Answer (score 0):

To start with your second question: yes you have to read the dynamically sized bits from an 8bit bytestream. You have to keep track of the size you are reading, and the number of unused bits left from previous read operations (used for correctly putting the 'next byte' from the file).

IIRC there is a minimum code size of 8 bits, which would give you a clear code of 256 (base 10) and an End Of Input of 257. The first stored code is then 258.

I am not sure why you did not looked up the source of one of the public domain graphics libraries. I know I did not because back in 1989 (!) there were no libraries to use and no internet with complete descriptions. I had to implement a decoder from an example executable (for MS-DOS from Compuserve) that could display images and a few GIF files, so I know that can be done (but it is not the most efficient way of spending your time).